# MySQL Syntax Error When Creating a Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger but I am getting a syntax error and I am not really sure why I am.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Section_Insert AFTER INSERT ON Section
    -> FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    -> INSERT INTO Audit(changeTime, tableName, Action) VALUES (NOW(), 'Section', 'INSERT');
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

Comment: Change the delimiter before you use `CREATE`, and change it back when you're finished.

Answer (score 0):

The following may be useful:

```sql
DELIMITER //

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `Section_Insert`//
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Section`//

CREATE TABLE `Section` (
     `changeTime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
     `tableName` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
     `Action` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
)//

CREATE TRIGGER `Section_Insert` AFTER INSERT ON `Section`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `Audit`(`changeTime`, `tableName`, `Action`) VALUES (NOW(), 'Section', 'INSERT');
END//

DELIMITER ;
```